# how to stop eventListener and reactivate it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys I have this code

```
var clicks = 0;
$('.card').on('click', function(){
    if(cardOpend === 5){
        //SOME CODE

    }else{
        clicks++;
        if(clicks === 2){
            $('.card').off('click');
        }
    }
    setTimeOut(function(){
        $('.card').on('click');
    }, 1000);
});
```

but unfortunately this doesn't work

I wanna stop the event listener for one second and then get it back to work.

**More Details** :

I'm trying to build memory card game 
if the player clicks on first card it will open and then the next card 
if there are no match stop click event to prevent the player from clicking on other card while a function show's the player that there are no match and then when card flips down the event reactivate and back to work.

```js
function shuffle(array) {

    'use strict';

    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}
//ALL VARIABLES
const DOMString = {
    container: $('.deck'),
    card: '.card',
    cardOpend: [],
    gameIsStarted: false,
    matches: 0,
    moves: 0
};

const cards = ['fa-diamond', 'fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa-anchor', 'fa-bolt', 'fa-cube', 'fa-anchor', 'fa-leaf', 'fa-bicycle', 'fa-diamond', 'fa-bomb', 'fa-leaf', 'fa-bomb', 'fa-bolt', 'fa-bicycle', 'fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa-cube'];


//FUNCTIONS
function creatUI(){
    let cardsShuffel = shuffle(cards);
    cardsShuffel.forEach((cur) => {
        DOMString.container.append('<li class="card"><i class="fa ' + cur + '"></i></li>');
    });
}

function startGame(){
    //flip Card when user click
    $(DOMString.card).on('click', function(){
        //ADD Calsses
        $(this).toggleClass('flipInY open show');
        //push the opend card into the Array
        DOMString.cardOpend.push($(this));
        //Start The game
        DOMString.gameIsStarted = true;
        //Check if there are a match
        if(DOMString.cardOpend.length === 2){
            if(DOMString.cardOpend[0][0].firstChild.classList[1] === DOMString.cardOpend[1][0].firstChild.classList[1]){
                DOMString.cardOpend[0][0].classList.add('match');
                DOMString.cardOpend[1][0].classList.add('match');

                //clear cardOpend array
                DOMString.cardOpend = [];

                //Increase Matches
                DOMString.matches++;

                //Increase Moves
                DOMString.moves++;
            }else{
                //add wrong class to opend cards
                DOMString.cardOpend[0][0].classList.add('wrong');
                DOMString.cardOpend[1][0].classList.add('wrong');

                //reclose all opend cards
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(DOMString.card).removeClass('open show wrong');
                    $(DOMString.card).removeClass('open show wrong');

                    //set cardOpend array to empty
                    DOMString.cardOpend = [];
                }, 1000);

                //Increase Moves
                DOMString.moves++;
            }
        }
    });
}


//CALL FUNCTIONS
creatUI();
startGame();
```

Comment: Can you please describe what you're trying to do a little more clearly. It's really not clear from your current description nor the code.

Comment: You need to look at the setTimeout part of your code it is not going to do what you may be thinking it's doing, and possibly triggering an error due to use of the wrong character case

Comment: Looks like throttling clicks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry man i edited the question and explained what is my question

Comment: @MolhamAlNasr check responses please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something with cards flipping, without cancer:

```js
let clicks = 0;
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
let addHandler;
const delay = x => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, x));
const handler = e => {
  if (clicks == -1) // Blocked
    return;

  const card = e.target;
  card.classList.toggle("flipped");
  if (false /* placeholder */ ) {
    //SOME CODE
  } else {
    clicks++;
    if (clicks == 2) {
      clicks = -1; // Block further clicks

      card.addEventListener("transitionend", async() => {
        // Reset after 1s
        await delay(1000);

        clicks = 0;
        cards.forEach(c => {
          c.classList.remove("flipped");
          c.removeEventListener("click", handler);
        });
        cards.forEach(addHandler);
      }, {
        once: true
      });
    }
  }
}
addHandler = card => card.addEventListener("click", handler, {
  once: true
});
cards.forEach(addHandler);
```

```css
.card {
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  will-change: transform;
}

.card.flipped {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<button class="card">Card 1</button>
<button class="card">Card 2</button>
<button class="card">Card 3</button>
<button class="card">Card 4</button>
```

Comment: Sorry man i was late to reply on your answer 
unfortunately it does't work on my original code i've edited the question and added the original code maybe other people can use it too

Comment: You should adapt the core principles, not try to copy it. Also, don't use jQuery.

Comment: Yeah thanks it works, the problem was the jQuery code

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `$('.card').on('click')` is not a function, to reactivate it, you must pass to `setTimeout` a function, something like this:

```
var clicks = 0;
var onClickFunction = function(){
    if(cardOpend === 5){
        //SOME CODE

    }else{
        clicks++;
        if(clicks === 2){
            $('.card').off('click');
        }
    }
    setTimeOut(function() {
        $('.card').off('click', onClickFunction); // Avoid multiple listeners
        $('.card').on('click', onClickFunction);
    }, 1000);
};
$('.card').on('click', onClickFunction);
```

**EDIT**

But, if you're trying to prevent the click on an element during an animation, you can just check a class to prevent the click event during the animation, using `event.preventDefault` and `event.stopPropagation`.

```
function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.classList.contains('loading')){
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        return;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) (might be useful, but maybe not, as it still can execute per element. then again, jquery should not be used at all)

Comment: I guess the problem is related to preventDefault

Comment: Sorry man i was late to reply on your answer 
unfortunately it does't work i've edited the question and added the original code maybe other people can use it too